# Any difference between $Pr(A=1, B=1)$ and $Pr(A=1 \cap B=1)$?

Tags: probability

Are the two notations interchangable? Do they all mean the joint probability of $A=1$ and $B=1$? Maybe $Pr(A=1 \cap B=1)$ is illegal? We can only write $Pr(A\cap B)$?

Comment: Yes, it means the same thing.  The comma is stating another condition that must hold, so: $$P[\{A=1\}\cap \{B=1\}] = P[A=1, B=1]$$ where $A$ and $B$ are random variabes and $\{A=1\}$ and $\{B=1\}$ are events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This style of notation is pretty frequent in probability.

When you see something like, where $X$ is a random variable,

$$P(X = 5)$$

you should think of "$X = 5$" in the parenthesis as the set

$$ \{ \omega \in \Omega | X(\omega) = 5 \}$$

where $\Omega$ is the sample space of $X$ (i.e., $X : \Omega  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$). With this style of notation, commas are used to mean intersection, so

$$ P(X = 5, Y \le 7)$$

is equivalent to

$$P(\{ \omega \in \Omega|X(\omega) = 5\} \cap \{\omega \in \Omega|Y(\omega) \le 7\})$$

Notice how the former, more concise notation is easier to read and understand, while the latter, although still formally correct, is quite cluttered.

Imagine, without the convenient notation, trying to describe something like

$$ P(X = 5, Y = 12, A = 3, B \le 12)$$

Ouch.

Using this notation, it is correct, as mentioned in the comments, that

$$P(A = 1 \cap B = 1) = P( A = 1, B = 1)$$

although the latter is a bit more readable and more often used.

Also,

$$P(A\cap B)$$

in your case probably isn't what you want, as I'm assuming your $A$ and $B$ are random variables, so their intersection is not useful in this context (it's hard to make sense of their intersection in this context, as it's a subset of $\Omega \times \mathbb{R}$).

Comment: If x={1,2}, Y={B,G} then the product space is { (1,B)......}
Then P(X=1, Y=B) = 0.25. Where is the intersection..I can’t imagine it as an intersection. Could you please help me